# How to change values of elements of a 3D array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am still a beginner and I've been looking for an answer to this problem for a few hours but found nothing that works for me.

Anyway, I have to create a 3D array representing airplanes of different sizes, for example, Boeing 777 has 5 rows and 3 columns, Boeing 747 has 10 rows and 5 columns.
I created the array in my main method like this:

```
int[][][] seating=new int[5][][];
int i = 0; rows = 0, columns = 0;

for (i = 0; i < seating.length; i++) {
        if(boeNum[i] == 747){
            rows = 10;
            columns = 5;
            seating[i] = new int[rows][columns];
        }
        else {
            rows = 5;
            columns = 3;
            seating[i] = new int[rows][columns];
        }
}
```

Note that I have 5 airplanes, of 2 type:

```
public static int[] boeingNum(){
    int[] boeNum={777,747,777,747,777};
    return boeNum;
}
```

Now I have to let the user choose to reserve a seat (the seat will be selected randomly on a specific plane, let's say for example seating[1][][], a 777) so when he decides to reserve a seat, one of the 0s in the elements of seating[1][][] will change to 1, but now here's the problem, when I try to reserve another seat at a 747 I get

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

I figured out that this happens because rows and columns variables are fixed on 5,3 respectively,  or am I misunderstanding? And how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that `boeNum` is a local variable, you can access it only within `boeingNum(){}`. You need to call that function to create a fixed array of planes:

```
int i = 0;

final int[] boeNum = boeingNum();   // you were missing this line?
int[][][] seating=new int[boeNum.length][][];

for (i = 0; i < seating.length; i++) {
        int rows = 0, columns = 0;

        if(boeNum[i] == 747){
            rows = 10;
            columns = 5;
        }
        else {
            rows = 5;
            columns = 3;
        }

        seating[i] = new int[rows][columns];
}
```